# cocoapods error : ~ target has frameworks with conflicting names: ~

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

My problem is pretty simple and stackoverflow has many 'similar' problems but couldn't find the exact one. Maybe too easy to solve? Anyway, here is the problem:

I use X in podfile like this:

`pod 'X', '3.3.4'`

and when I added the follwing,

`pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.17'`

I got this error from pod:

`[!] The ‘Pods-WayStride’ target has frameworks with conflicting names: mapbox.framework.`

And yes, the `X` that I've been using uses 'mapbox.framework', probably part of it, already, as I can see it under `'Pods > Pods > Steerpath-Map-SDK > Frameworks > Mapbox.framework'` in Project navigator of Xcode.

Because of this error, when I tried to compile using Xcode (ver 9.4, with swift), I get this error on the line of 'import MapboxDirections':

`No such module 'MapboxDirections'`

What can I do?

My Podfile is very simple:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.3'

# by SP
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://bitbucket.org/nimbledevices/steerpath-sdk-ios-podspec.git'
source 'https://bitbucket.org/nimbledevices/steerpath-mapbox-ios-podspec.git'

# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

target 'WayStride' do

  # platform :ios, '8.0'

   pod 'Steerpath', '3.3.4'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
   pod 'Mixpanel-swift'
   pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 3.0.1'

   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

   pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.17'

#  target 'WayStrideTests' do
#    inherit! :search_paths
#    # Pods for testing
#  end
#
#  target 'WayStrideUITests' do
#    inherit! :search_paths
#    # Pods for testing
#  end

end
```

Comment: Pod Mapbox as dependence for Steerpath and MapboxNavigation, but different versions Mapbox.framework used in pods. 
Change version pods Steerpath and MapboxNavigation so that under the Mapbox there is one version. You can also try to specify the dependence on the Mapbox - pod Mapbox

Comment: @ViR Thanks for quick response. 1. I don't want to lower version for either of them, since I want better feature/less bugs. 2. If version of Mapbox is the only problem, then could you tell me how to specify the dependence on Mapbox from MapboxNavigation? (Steerpath uses Mapbox 4.0.0 while MapboxNavigation uses > 4.0.0 and current Mapbox version is 4.0.2 (https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

How i resolved it

Step one : open Podfile under ios/App/podfile

comment this lines out

#pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'

#pod 'CordovaPluginsResources', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'

after this, run Pod install

now should work just fine

OR, write like this, take off the CordovaPlugins, as it already installed by the first

```
def capacitor_pods
  #Automatic Capacitor Pod dependencies, do not delete
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  #pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  pod 'CordovaPluginsStatic', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  pod 'CordovaPluginsResources', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  # Do not delete
end
```